# "Not Long After" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Doest it mean "from"? The writer wants to conclude that human brain is asymmetrical from the outset of existence:

> The part of the brain responsible for control and movement is located in the left hemisphere, and the findings above suggest that the human brain was already asymmetrical **not long after** 3 million years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase

> not long after

is a **relative** period of time after, since, or starting from a **reference event**.

How much time is dependent on context:

> He went outside and **not long after** it started to rain

would usually be measured in minutes.

> **Not long after** Tyrannosaurous Rex disappeared Stegosauruses roamed the earth

would be measured in millions of years, otherwise known as geologic time.

In your example

> the human brain was already asymmetrical in its structure and function **not long after** 2 million years ago

would be measured in tens of thousands of years and put the starting time more recent than 2 million years ago, otherwise known as evolutionary time since generations of a species need to occur for change to happen

NOTE: There seems to be anecdotal evidence that humans are not the only mammals with a preference for handedness [here](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2015/jun/11/left-handed-cats-handedness-archive-1955), [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/5963820/Domestic-cats-can-be-left-or-right-handed-scientists-find.html), and [here](http://mentalfloss.com/article/52812/are-cats-and-dogs-right-or-left-handed-too).  Gives real meaning to the term *southpaw*.